# getElementById and getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

As in mentioned code,I used `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` but it is **not working**.

It is giving **error** as

> *f[0].getElementById is not a function* inside a console.

```js
let f = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');
console.log(f[0].getElementById('p1'));
document.write(f[0].getElementById('p1'))
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <section class="sec" id="mysec1">
    <p class="para" id="p1">Para1</p>
    <p class="para" id="p2">Para2</p>
    <p class="para" id="p3">Para3</p>
    <p class="para" id="p4">Para4</p>
    <p class="para" id="p5">Para5</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sec" id="mysec2">
    <p class="para" id="pp1">Apara1</p>
    <p class="para" id="pp2">Apara2</p>
    <p class="para" id="pp3">Apara3</p>
    <p class="para" id="pp4">Apara4</p>
    <p class="para" id="pp5">Apara5</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is function of `document` object.

If you want to get p1 inside class sec you can use `querySelector` as

```
document.querySelector('.sec #p1')
```

```html
div id="maindiv">
    <section class="sec" id="mysec1">
      <p class="para" id="p1">Para1</p>
      <p class="para" id="p2">Para2</p>
      <p class="para" id="p3">Para3</p>
      <p class="para" id="p4">Para4</p>
      <p class="para" id="p5">Para5</p>
    </section>
    <section class="sec" id="mysec2">
      <p class="para" id="pp1">Apara1</p>
      <p class="para" id="pp2">Apara2</p>
      <p class="para" id="pp3">Apara3</p>
      <p class="para" id="pp4">Apara4</p>
      <p class="para" id="pp5">Apara5</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  
  <!-- Project -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

let f = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');
console.log(document.querySelector('.sec #p1'));
//document.write(document.querySelector('.sec #p1'))

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) response is the array of DOM element.

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is the function of the `document`, not DOM element.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('p1'));
document.write(document.getElementById('p1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementById` is a method of the object `document`. So you need to change your code a bit:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('p1'));
document.write(document.getElementById('p1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

bro why using core js use jquery and make your life simple:
var  f =$('#mysec1  > #p1'); using jquery

Answer (score 0):

and if u really want to use core js use it like this:

```
var myDomElement = document.getElementById( "foo" ); // A plain DOM element.
 
$( myDomElement ).find( "a" );
```